# Nuclide don't find flow

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I'm beginning my studies with react native, however, when I opened a project with atom and the nuclide package, it gives me a message saying that wasn't possible to locate the flow binary in the PATH.

From a terminal I had run:

```
$ which flow
# Outputs: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/bin/flow

$ echo $PATH | tr -s ":" "\n"
# Outputs: /home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/bin ... and other paths
```

So, any clues why atom don't find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my problem, it seems that nuclide has a setting to add the path to the flow binary. To change it you can

1. Go your terminal and type `which flow` to find where your Flow executable lives and copy and paste that path.
2. Fire up Nuclide, go to Preferences > Installed Packages > Nuclide > Settings
3. Scroll down to `Nuclide-flow` and change the path of `Path to Flow executable` to be the value of `which flow` from terminal.

Comment: Where should Flow be installed?